# How do I add MSSQL php module in Jelastic

Tags: php, sql-server, jelastic

I am developing an application in PHP & MySQL that needs to integrate with Microsoft database SQL Server client. We've done the integration into our development environment, but discover that Jelastic not have the mssql module.

In the Jelastic documentation says that it is possible to upload additional modules for php (http://docs.jelastic.com/php-extensions). Does anyone know how I compile MSSQL to use it in Jelastic?

Is there any way to connect to a SQL Server database in Jelastic, via PHP, without adding a new module?

Comment: Your hosting provider should be able to handle this for you. It's best for the module to be compiled on the system where it'll be installed.

Comment: Already I contacted the Hosting, before you even open this topic, support reported that as Jelastic is a cloud service, they can only act on issues related to Grid infrastructure and control panel, the inclusion of any module is up to user.

Comment: @Edu, please give us a hint about your current hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you experience any difficulties or have any questions, using Jelastic, you can contact support team of your chosen hosting provider. To do this, click on the top right button "Help" and choose "Contact Support" on your Dashboard:

[image: Contact Support]

Comment: Already I contacted the Hosting, before you even open this topic, support reported that as Jelastic is a cloud service, they can only act on issues related to Grid infrastructure and control panel, the inclusion of any module is up to user.

Comment: @Edu Wow... use a different Jelastic partner! Here's your full list of options - https://jelastic.com/about/hosting-partners/